# Python: Pandas dataframe from Series of dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe:

```
type(original)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

which includes the series object `original['user']`:

```
type(original['user'])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

`original['user']` points to a number of dicts:

```
type(original['user'].ix[0])
dict
```

Each dict has the same keys:

```
original['user'].ix[0].keys()

[u'follow_request_sent',
 u'profile_use_background_image',
 u'profile_text_color',
 u'id',
 u'verified',
 u'profile_location',
 # ... keys removed for brevity
]
```

Above is (part of) one of the dicts of `user` fields in a tweet from [tweeter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest). I want to build a data frame from these dicts.

When I try to make a data frame directly, I get only one column for each row and this column contains the whole dict:

```
pd.DataFrame(original['user'][:2])
    user
0   {u'follow_request_sent': False, u'profile_use_...
1   {u'follow_request_sent': False, u'profile_use_..
```

When I try to create a data frame using from_dict() I get the same result:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(original['user'][:2])

    user
0   {u'follow_request_sent': False, u'profile_use_...
1   {u'follow_request_sent': False, u'profile_use_..
```

Next I tried a list comprehension which returned an error:

```
item = [[k, v] for (k,v) in users]
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

When I create a data frame from a single row, it nearly works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(original['user'].ix[0])
df.reset_index()

    index   contributors_enabled    created_at  default_profile     default_profile_image   description     entities    favourites_count    follow_request_sent     followers_count     following   friends_count   geo_enabled     id  id_str  is_translation_enabled  is_translator   lang    listed_count    location    name    notifications   profile_background_color    profile_background_image_url    profile_background_image_url_https  profile_background_tile     profile_image_url   profile_image_url_https     profile_link_color  profile_location    profile_sidebar_border_color    profile_sidebar_fill_color  profile_text_color  profile_use_background_image    protected   screen_name     statuses_count  time_zone   url     utc_offset  verified
0   description     False   Mon May 26 11:58:40 +0000 2014  True    False       {u'urls': []}   0   False   157
```

It works almost like I want it to, except it sets the `description` field as the default index.

Each of the dicts has 40 keys but I only need about 10 of them and I have 28734 rows in data frame.

How can I filter out the keys which I do not need?

Comment: You should use read_json here to get this into a single DataFrame. Using a DataFrame of DataFrames is a bad idea.

Comment: @andy-hayden, I thought about it but it requires additional querying database. I store data in local mongo db, but I want to reduce interaction between python and mongo.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

what I would try to do is the following:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(list(original['user']))
```

this will convert the series to list then pass it to pandas dataframe and it should take care of the rest.

Comment: It does not work, I get a dataframe with dtype of object(dict), what I expected was that the keys of the dict would be the columns of the dataframe

Comment: which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: mine was pandas 0.23.0 with python 3.6

Comment: I recommend preserving the original index as well, `new_df = pd.DataFrame(original['user'].tolist(), index=original.index)`

Comment: Does not work if the series has also nulls in it!

Comment: @EduMarín could you please give an example for "...series has also nulls in it"? thanks!

Answer (score 27):

`df = original['user'].apply(pd.Series)`

works well

[credit](http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_expand_cells_containing_lists.html)

Comment: Also this one may be really slow

Comment: This is insanely clever. If you have a Series with dtype `object` and the objects are identically-keyed dictionaries, do this.

Comment: Really very slow. On my test of 5000 strings `series.apply(pd.Series)` is 300 times (!) slower than `pd.DataFrame(series.values.tolist())`. Seems like constructing Series for each string is costy.

Comment: Slow but works perfectly when the series of dictionaries has nulls.

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```py
series_of_dicts = original['user']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    series_of_dicts.values, index=series_of_dicts.index
)
```

Or if you have a list or other iterable of dicts, then a simple

`pd.DataFrame.from_records(iterable_of_dicts)`

works.

[Docs for DataFrame.from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html)

I haven't timed it, but I'd imagine it should be pretty fast, since it this is exactly what DataFrame.from_records() was made for.

Comment: Also good since this keeps the index if it has meaning.