# Convert series of dict and concat to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

My dataframe

```
                             Items  Count  ScannedCount  
0  {'comp': {'S': '2019-08-02'}...   1032          1032 
1  {'comp': {'S': '2019-08-27'}...   1032          1032
```

The items series looks like this

```
{'comp': {'S': '2019-08-02T16:54:55.035196+03:00'}, 'ID': {'S': '336'}, 'dID': {'S': '1763523'}, 'fname': {'S': '558012'}}
```

Using the second answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681906/python-pandas-dataframe-from-series-of-dict) allows me to convert the series to a dataframe.
The issues is how to scale that operation since it happens on each row,

Current approach:

Looping through each row and concat them into a series (very slow)

```
item_df = pd.DataFrame(df['Items'].iloc[i]) for i in range(df.shape[0])]).reset_index(drop=True), df], axis=1)
```

Concat the results with the original dataframe

`df = pd.concat([temp, df], axis=1)`

I believe the `for` loop in the first part is the bottleneck.
Is there a faster way to convert a series to dataframe and concat it back to the original dataframe.

Expected output:

```
                 comp   ID  dID      fname   Count  ScannedCount  
0  2019-08-02T16:54:55  336 1763523  548012  1032   1032
1  2019-09-01T14:52:24  336 1763523  528012  1032   1032
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve. Could add expected output? Is it something like this:
`df = pd.concat([df.drop(['Items'], axis=1), df['Items'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)` ?

Comment: added expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this more columnar solution. It works with assumptation that there is always 'S' key in dictionary.

```
df_tmp = df['Items'].apply(pd.Series)
for c in df_tmp.columns:
    df[c] = df_tmp[c].apply(lambda x: x.get('S'))
df = df.drop(columns='Items')
```

Comment: wow your code is 6x faster than mine, at the pythonic level looping over the columns  vs the rows was the trick

Answer (score 0):

Looks like iterating over all the df is inevitable. I'm not sure if it's better, but I know the pandas way of doing so is by using [`iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html).

In the docs they also mention [`itertuples()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas.DataFrame.itertuples) for specific use cases, but again, I'm no expert here.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

test data:

```
import pandas as pd
test_data = {'item' : [{'comp': {'S': '2019-08-02T16:54:55.035196+03:00'}, 'ID': {'S': '336'}, 'dID': {'S': '1763523'}, 'fname': {'S': '558012'}}, {'comp': {'S': '2019-09-02T16:54:55.035196+03:00'}, 'ID': {'S': '336'}, 'dID': {'S': '1763523'}, 'fname': {'S': '558012'}}], 'Count': [1032,1032], 'ScannedCount':[1032,1032]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_data)

Out[64]:  
                                                    item  Count  ScannedCount
    0  {'comp': {'S': '2019-08-02T16:54:55.035196+03:...   1032          1032
    1  {'comp': {'S': '2019-09-02T16:54:55.035196+03:...   1032          1032
```

As far as i understand, you try to get something like this:

```
def extract(row):

    item_series = pd.Series({k:v for k,v in row['item'].items()})
    result = row.append(item_series)

    return result

df = df.apply(extract, axis = 1)
```

This gives you:

```
Out[67]: 
                                            comp            ID               dID  \
    0  {'S': '2019-08-02T16:54:55.035196+03:00'}  {'S': '336'}  {'S': '1763523'}   
    1  {'S': '2019-09-02T16:54:55.035196+03:00'}  {'S': '336'}  {'S': '1763523'}   

             fname  
    0  {'S': '558012'}  
    1  {'S': '558012'}  

## skipped some columns for clarity
```

Comment: added the expected output