# Convert Pandas serie to a structured pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas serie.

```
0     "{"ExchangeID":6,"Symbol":'E:AI',"Periodicite"...
1     "{"ExchangeID":6,"Symbol":'E:CS',"Periodicite"...
2     "{"ExchangeID":6,"Symbol":'E:BNP',"Periodicite...
```

How can I transform this serie to a structured pandas Dataframe like that

| ExchangeID | Symbol | Periodicite | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 'E:AI' | J |  |
| 6 | 'E:CS' | J |  |
| 6 | 'E:BNP' | J |  |

Thanks you

Comment: `.apply(pd.Series)`.

Comment: Seems like a dupe from [this SO question: Python: Pandas dataframe from Series of dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681906/python-pandas-dataframe-from-series-of-dict)

Comment: You seem to have invalid python in your example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert json string to dict then apply `pd.Series` to convert dict to columns

```py
import ast


s = s.apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(pd.Series)

# or

s = s.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(ast.literal_eval(x)))
```

```py
print(s)

   ExchangeID Symbol
0           6   E:AI
1           6   E:CS
2           6  E:BNP
```